# I am trying to use Datetime in a class then call it in my main method

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a class that is using the `datetime` struct and call it in my main method

```cs
namespace Week9ObjectsAndClassesHW
{
    public class DayOfWeekHelper
    {        
        public static void PrintDayOfWeek()
        {
            var dateValue = new DateTime();
            Console.WriteLine(dateValue.ToString("dddd"));
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
var instance = new DayOfWeekHelper();
instance.PrintDayOfWeek(10, 31, 2022);
```

Comment: It looks like you accidentally a question. Is the homework you're supposed to be reading going to teach you about method parameters and static versus instance methods?

Comment: Yes it is hw but we were told to Google it I figured it out after a few anyways

Answer (score 2):

If you want to pass some parameters `(10, 31, 2000)` to `PrintDayOfWeek` you should declare them:

```
public class DayOfWeekHelper
{
   // Method declares formal parameters: month, day, year.
   // When we call th method, say PrintDayOfWeek(10, 31, 2022)
   // we assign some values to these formal parameters to be used
   // in method execution
   // static : we ensure that method doesn't instance (this) 
   public static void PrintDayOfWeek(int month, int day, int year)
   {
       //TODO: validate month, day, year here

       // Here we use formal parameters to create DateTime of interes:
       // we want a date (and then day of week) 
       // which corresponds to year, month, day
       var dateValue = new DateTime(year, month, day);
       Console.WriteLine(dateValue.ToString("dddd"));
   }
}
```

then you can put

```
// Since method is static it doesn't work with instance, 
// thus you should use class name instead of creating instance
DayOfWeekHelper.PrintDayOfWeek(10, 31, 2022);
```

Comment: @CodeCaster: my bad, there are several issues, not just one

Comment: I think OP is supposed to learn about parameter passing and instance vs static, and that they should study some more. We can answer this question from experience and context, but they appear rather clueless about the task at hand. Can you perhaps explain what parameters and instance methods are?